# mitigate long tail problem in recommendation using Earth mover's distance with Latent Dirichlet Allocation

Tags: system, long-integer, recommendation-engine, tail

Can reduce A long tail problem in recommendation with EMD and LDA? Can these techniques work for this?

I am trying EMD and LDA techniques for reducing long tail problems in the recommendation and improving the personalized recommendation.